# Improving GitLab Pipeline Performance

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, devops, pipeline

I am trying to improve the performance of my pipeline, but I'm experiencing significant delays during the restore stage. It currently takes approximately 4 minutes for both the restore and build stages to complete.

Here's an example of my pipeline:

```
build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - globalrunner
  script:
    - mkdir src

    - dotnet restore "example.csproj"
    - dotnet restore "example.csproj"
    - echo "Restore success"

    - dotnet build "example.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build 
    - dotnet build "example.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build 

  only:
    - tags
build-artifacts:
  stage: build-artifacts

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./app/publish/

  script:
    - dotnet publish "example.csproj" -c Release -o ./app/publish
    - dotnet publish "example.csproj" -c Release -o ./app/publish
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a cache for dependencies which will prevent the pipeline from having to download dependencies from scratch each time it runs. You can use the actions/cache@v3
2. Try different runner, if possible
3. Use a parallel runner. This will allow the pipeline to run multiple jobs at the same time.

Comment: i used `dotnet build --parallel "./Host.Core/Host.Core.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build --no-restore` but it gave me an error
`MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
  Switches appended by response files:
Switch: --parallel
For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"`

Comment: It means dotnet build command does not support the --parallel switch. To build multiple projects in parallel, you can use the MSBuild command-line tool with the /m switch. The /m switch allows you to specify the maximum number of projects to build simultaneously.
ou can also use the MSBuild command to build multiple projects in parallel by passing a list of project files to the command.